# PopupMenu in older android API

Tags: android, android-support-library, popupmenu

can I use PopupMenu in older API without using support library v7 ?

I am already using support library v4, but it's not enough for this

and what is the alternative, if I don't use it ?

Comment: Did you mean popupmenu? That's only available since API 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) is only available in API 11 or higher. As far as I can tell from the documentation it is not included in any support library and thus cannot be used on a lower api version. You should probably use an alternative like a `Dialog` or `ContextMenu` in those situations. It's not the same thing but kind of close.

Answer (score 0):

You must import support v7 in your application same as follow:
[Adding libraries with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)

and in your project import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu and then compile your code with that your popup menu is compatible for android 2.2 and above.